# Multiple Or Conditions in a Countifs Statement

Tags: excel-formula, countif

Is it possible to have multiple OR conditions in a `countifs` statement?

I am trying to write a statement that counts the number of records where the relationship is either 'Contractor' OR 'Supplier' AND if the Severity is either 'Serious' OR Major.  The first OR condition will work, but only the first condition in the second OR statement is being picked up.  Here is what i have written:

```
=(COUNTIFS(Data!F:F,{"Contractor","Supplier"},Data!E:E,{"Serious","Major"}))
```

Comment: is this in Excel? Maybe you could add extra tags like *Excel-Formula* or even just *Excel*

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMPRODUCT((Data!F:F="Contractor")+(Data!F:F="Supplier"),(Data!E:E="Serious")+(Data!E:E="Major"))`

- The `(Data!F:F="Contractor")` will produce an array of TRUE/FALSE the size of column F, with TRUE only where Column F is "Contractor".
- The `(Data!F:F="Supplier")` will produce an array of TRUE/FALSE the size of column F, with TRUE only where Column F is "Supplier".
- the above two arrays are "ADDED" - this converts them to 1/0s instead and adds the two arrays together, producing an array the size of column F, with 1 / 0 s, with 1s where cells in column F are EITHER "Contractor" or "Supplier".
- the same for "Serious"/"Major"
- inside the SUMPRODUCT the two arrays with 1&0s are MULTIPLIED together, so will return a 1 ONLY when there is a 1 in BOTH arrays so: `F is {"Contractor OR "Supplier"} AND E is {"Serious" OR "Major"}`
- the whole array is then summed (by the `SUMPRODUCT()` ) to return the COUNT of rows that match the criteria (as a single number)